# Implement timeout for a callback passed as an argument in a synchronous method

Tags: java

I have to make a synchronous call to the method and one of the arguments to this method is a callback. 
For instance callSync(callback). How can I set a timeout for this callback. If I don't receive a callback in n sec, an exception should be thrown.

```
transaction.submit(callback);
...................

 private AsynTransaction callBack = new AsynTransaction.Stub() {
        @Override
        public void callback(byte[] messageBytes) throws RemoteException {
        }

}
```

Comment: You have just posted requirements. You should write code and ask for what doesn't work. At least post you're call back and the Calling method and and as a comment the place you need a timer

Comment: That's not a standard idiom in Java, and you can't just put timeouts on synchronous calls. In fact you can't get this done with synchronous calls at all, you need something like `Future.get()` or similar, where you can put a timeout, but this requires asynchronous processing.

Comment: I am not putting timeouts on synchronous calls. I want a timeout on the callback function.